# ¿Como consigo que un array de numeros y letras muestre por separado el resultado de la suma de los números y la palabra entera?

Tags: javascript, array

El array seria el siguiente:

```
const array_A = ['H',1,'o',2,'l',3,'a']
```

y lo que quiero conseguir es que se vea esto '6 Hola'.

Answer (score 7):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
const array_A = ['H',1,'o',2,'l',3,'a']
var palabra = "";
var suma = 0;

array_A.forEach(function(caracter) {
  if (isNaN(caracter)) {
    palabra += caracter;
  } else {
    suma += caracter;
  }
});
console.log(suma, palabra);
```

Answer (score 1):

aquí te dejo cómo se haría con algo de programación funcional (filter, reduce) e interpolación de string (ES6) por si quieres probar...

```js
const array_A = ['H',1,'o',2,'l',3,'a']

let str = array_A.filter(item => typeof item === 'string').join('');
let num = array_A.filter(item => typeof item === 'number');
let sumNum = num.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val);
console.log(`${sumNum} ${str}`);
```

Saludos