# ¿Como consigo que un array con numeros y letras y un espacio se sumen y formen una palabra?

Tags: javascript, array, bucles, ecmascript-6

El ejercicio sería así:

```
const array_A = ["H",3,"o",4,"l",5,"a",6," ",7,"M",8,"u",9,"n",10,"d",11,"o"]

const array_B = ["s",1,"t",2,"a",3,"c",4,"k"]

const array_C = ["o",1,"v",2,"e",-3,"r","f","l","o","w"]
```

Se tendría que ver el sumatorio de los números y la palabra con el espacio en string.

```
// '63 Hola Mundo

// '10 stack'

// '0 overflow'
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Como consigo que un array de numeros y letras muestre por separado el resultado de la suma de los números y la palabra entera?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/204896/como-consigo-que-un-array-de-numeros-y-letras-muestre-por-separado-el-resultado)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el método `reduce()` en una función que recibe un vector y devuelva un objeto con la salida deseada.

```
function output(array) {
  return array.reduce((out, current)=>{
    typeof current == "string" ?out.text+=current:out.count+=current;
    return out;
  },{text:'',count:0})
}
```

Te dejo un link con un ejemplo.

[ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-group-by-text-number)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con la siguiente función que cree:

```
function reformular(arreglo){
    //variable donde voy sumando los números
    var n = 0;
    //variable donde voy sumando las letras para formar la oración
    var msg = '';
    //Recorres el arreglo
    for(var i in arreglo){
      //En caso de que el elemento actual de la iteración sea un numero entero
      if(/^-?\d+$/.test(arreglo[i])){
        //Sumas el valor que tenia n el nuevo numero encontrado
        n += parseInt(arreglo[i]);
      } else {
        //De lo contrario concatenas lo que tenia msg al nuevo caracter encontrado
        msg += arreglo[i];
      }
    }
    return `${n} ${msg}`;
}
```

Asi es como la llamarias, asumiendo que ya tienes declarado los 3 arreglos como estaban en tu pregunta:

```
console.log(reformular(array_A));
console.log(reformular(array_B));
console.log(reformular(array_C));
```

Puedes hacer la funcion de esta otra forma:

```
function reformular(arreglo){
    //variable donde voy sumando los números
    var n = 0;
    //variable donde voy sumando las letras para formar la oración
    var msg = '';
    arreglo.forEach(function(item){
      if(/^-?\d+$/.test(item)){
        n += parseInt(item);
      } else {
        msg += item;
      }
    })
    return `${n} ${msg}`;
}
```

Funciona de la misma manera la diferencia es que uso una funcion del objeto Array que me permite recorrer el arreglo sin tener que crear una sentencia iterativa o de ciclo uno mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Hola espero mi respuesta te sea de ayuda o aclare un poco como trabajar con arrays:

```
var handle_array = function(arr){
    a1 = arr.filter((element) => {
        return typeof(element) === 'number';
    });

    a2 = arr.filter((element) => {
        return typeof(element) !== 'number';
    });
    return a1.reduce((total, num) => total + num) + " " + a2.join("")
}

a1 = ["H",3,"o",4,"l",5,"a",6," ",7,"M",8,"u",9,"n",10,"d",11,"o"]
handle_array(a1)
```

Saludos (Y)